# Rails routes, rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I am attempting to create a route to a controller method, in order that it pass an rpsec condition. For some reason that escapes me, RSPEC will not accept the route.

Here is the rspec:

```
describe BooksController do
  describe 'searching AMZN' do
    it 'should call the model method that performs AMZN search' do
      post :search_tmdb, {:search_terms => 'hardware'}
    end
```

My routes file reads:

```
Rottenpotatoes::Application.routes.draw do

  resources :books

  post '/books/search_amzn'

  # map '/' to be a redirect to '/books'
  root :to => redirect('/books')
end
```

The controller action in books_controller.rb:

```
    def search_amzn
      @books = Books.find_in_amzn(params[:search_terms])
    end
```

I am clearly making an error in my route for I can't get away from this error message:

```
  1) MoviesController searching AMZN should call the model method that  performs AMZN search
     Failure/Error: post :search_amzn, {:search_terms => 'hardware'}
     ActionController::RoutingError:
       No route matches {:search_terms=>"hardware", :controller=>"books", :action=>"search_amzn"}
     # ./spec/controllers/books_controller_spec.rb:9:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Here are links to the complete files:

Routes.rb: http://pastebin.com/yKBeLLnY

Spec: http://pastebin.com/cU3nRSvE

Comment: `post :search_tmdb` here you are writing `search_tmdb` what is this and where its defined ? you are calling here post action and showing get route. :)

Comment: Are you sure that's the route that's causing the error?

Comment: @ Dave: Unless I am missing something beyond my knowledge base, that is the offending route.

Comment: @ Padreep: Good call, though it did not fix the error. `search_tmbd` is a controller action that I added to books_controller:

      `def search_tmbd
        @movies = Movie.find_in_tmbd(params[:search_terms])
      end`


Also, for purposes of the question I meant to use "search_amzn" as the dummy example, just tried to make the question more consistent in that regard.

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

`post :search_tmdb, {:search_terms => 'hardware'}`

to:

`get :search_tmdb, {:search_terms => 'hardware'}`

Also, in your routes file, change this:

`post '/books/search_amzn'`

to:

`post '/books/search_amzn', as: :search_tmdb`

Comment: I think that the problem is in my route.  The method should post the search_terms to the view.

Comment: The documentation makes it seem as though the route `post '/movies/search_tmbd/'` should be enought to map to the controller action, but I still keep getting the failure.  This is nuts.

Comment: Where in your routes are you defining a post action?

Comment: just added it to the question.

Comment: Thanks, but something isn't working.  I am guessing that I am missing something simple.  I included link to the specs and routes file in the edit. Also, here is the controller file: http://pastebin.com/Ax0U1AQN